# Can I pass to npm which DB connection to use using environment variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, attributes

I have a DB connection in a JS file

```js
const dbCredentials = {
  user: 'something',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'something',
  password: 'something',
  port: 1111,
};

export default dbCredentials;
```

I import this file in another place and do the connection and retrieve needed information from the postgres DB. These credentials are for local DB.

**The question:**
Now I also need to add new connection for circleCi (which has other DB connection parameters) and when running npm I need to specify to which DB to connect, local or circleCi.
I need to specify an Environment Variable which I will pass in npm script and by passing that Environment Variable, the connection will be done to circleCi.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `without environment variables`? How do detect your apps is running in a test (circle-ci) environment without referencing the node environment?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. After some research I think it can be done with Environment Variable, but don't know yet how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this problem with this solution

```js
let dbCredentials;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'CI') {
  dbCredentials = {
    user: 'ciUser',
    host: 'cirleCIhost',
    database: 'somthing',
    password: '',
    port: 1111,
  };
} else {
  dbCredentials = {
    user: 'user',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'dev',
    password: '',
    port: 1111,
  };
}

export default dbCredentials;
```

And I just need to run this command in terminal to specify that CI DB needs to be used

> NODE_ENV=CI npm run